# Does $(x_n)=\left((1+\frac{1}{3n})^{-3n/2}\right)$ converge and if it converges, decide the limit.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I missed this problem on my exam and I would really like to know how to do problems like this correctly for my upcoming final. I'm thoroughly confused on divergence and convergence and appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks in advance!

My guess was to use the definition of contractive (which wasn't close to correct) and by the remarks on the exam, I think what I should do is compare $1 +1/(3n)$ with $1 + 1/n$ (which converges to 1) and $1$ to any power would just be 1 right? I just want to know the correct way to do it.

Comment: Remove the outer pair of brackets on both sides; they are confusing you. Now have you ever heard of the number [e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29)?

Comment: Are you familiar with $(1+1/n)^n \to e?$

Comment: @zhw I've seen $e$ written that way before... How could I relate it to the sequence I have?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Tried tagging you above too, but I can only tag one user at a time.

Comment: Well it follows that $(1+1/3n)^{3n} \to e.$

Comment: @zhw. I'm sorry if this is an easy jump to make but how come you're able to make that assumption?

Comment: @zhw. It was also written on my exam as a hint that this sequence is a subsequence of a convergent sequence. If I can prove that this sequence is indeed a subsequence (maybe of $e$), would that be enough to imply that the subsequence also converges to $e$?

Comment: Sure, every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$
\bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{3n} \bigg)^{-3n/2} = \exp \bigg[ \frac{-3n}{2}\log \bigg(1 + \frac{1}{3n} \bigg)\bigg] = \exp \bigg[ \frac{-1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}o(1) \bigg] \to e^{-1/2}
$$
as $n$ grows indefinitely.

**Note.** We have applied the fact that $\log (1 + x) = x + o(x)$ as $x \to 0$, which is due to Taylor polynomial approximation of $x \mapsto \log (1+x)$ at $0$ for $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since we have 
$ \lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e $ (you should search the truth of this!) By this you can easily (e.g. change of variation) conclude that it converges $ e^{-\frac{1}{2}}. $

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$x_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)^{-3n/2}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(x_n)=-\frac{3n}2 \log\left(1+\frac{1}{3n}\right)$$ Now, remember that for small $x$, $\log(1+x)\approx x$. Replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{3n}$. So $$\log(x_n)\approx -\frac{3n}2 \times \frac{1}{3n}=-\frac 12$$